# Solr filters are them good?

Tags: xml, solr

Do you think my filters are good for french search?

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!--
     in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>      
    -->
    <!--
     Case insensitive stop word removal.
              add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
              analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" />        
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have some problems like "electricitré" which returns 6 occurences, when "electricite" returns 9 occurences.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Solr admin page to understand why `electricitré` and `electricite` doesn't give same results:

> http://exemple.com:8983/solr/#/yourCoreName/analysis?analysis.fieldvalue=electricit%C3%A9+electricite&analysis.query=electricit%C3%A9+electricite&analysis.fieldtype=text&verbose_output=1

Here I suppose this is due to the typo: `electricitré` instead of `electricité` without a **r**?

2. [Solr advises to use synonyms at index time](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory):

> Keep in mind that while the SynonymFilter will happily work with
>   synonyms containing multiple words (ie: "sea biscuit, sea biscit,
>   seabiscuit") The recommended approach for dealing with synonyms like
>   this, is to expand the synonym when indexing. This is because there
>   are two potential issues that can arrise at query time:
>
> 1. The Lucene QueryParser tokenizes on white space before giving any text
>      to the Analyzer, so if a person searches for the words sea biscit the
>      analyzer will be given the words "sea" and "biscit" seperately, and
>      will not know that they match a synonym.
> 2. Phrase searching (ie: "sea
>      biscit") will cause the QueryParser to pass the entire string to the
>      analyzer, but if the SynonymFilter is configured to expand the
>      synonyms, then when the QueryParser gets the resulting list of tokens
>      back from the Analyzer, it will construct a MultiPhraseQuery that will
>      not have the desired effect. This is because of the limited mechanism
>      available for the Analyzer to indicate that two terms occupy the same
>      position: there is no way to indicate that a "phrase" occupies the
>      same position as a term. For our example the resulting
>      MultiPhraseQuery would be "(sea | sea | seabiscuit) (biscuit |
>      biscit)" which would not match the simple case of "seabiscuit"
>      occuring in a document
>
> Even when you aren't worried about multi-word
>   synonyms, idf differences still make index time synonyms a good idea.
>   Consider the following scenario:
>
> - An index with a "text" field, which at query time uses the
>     SynonymFilter with the synonym TV, Televesion and expand="true"
> - Many
>     thousands of documents containing the term "text:TV"
> - A few hundred
>     documents containing the term "text:Television"
>
> A query for text:TV
>   will expand into (text:TV text:Television) and the lower docFreq for
>   text:Television will give the documents that match "Television" a much
>   higher score then docs that match "TV" comparably -- which may be
>   somewhat counter intuitive to the client. Index time expansion (or
>   reduction) will result in the same idf for all documents regardless of
>   which term the original text contained.

3. [Solr advises to use the `ElisionFilter` before `WordDelimiterFilter`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#French):

> Note: Its probably best to use the ElisionFilter before WordDelimiterFilter. This will prevent very slow phrase queries.

Comment: OK thanks i have changed. I have a second problem, my solr index 3 time a document. i dont know why